# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: reactjs

installing npm install --save react-dev-utils@11.0.4 and then running the react application throws the above error.

I checked multiple solution where they say to update the version of react-scripts. But I am using the latest version of it.